# value not found in akka Producer-Consumer with actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

i am following a tutorial to create a Producer Consumer with actors 
i made three files i.e Master.scala, Counter.scala and Parser.scala
i am getting **not found value** in two of my files(Counter.scala and Parser.scala)
 Parser.scala

```
 import akka.actor.Actor
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem
    import akka.actor.Props
    import akka.actor._
    case object Processed
    class Parser(counter: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    val pages=Pages(100000, "enwiki.xml")
    override def preStart{
    for(page<-pages.take(10))
    counter ! page
    }
    def receive={
    case Processed if pages.hasNext => counter ! pages.next
    case _ => context.stop(self)
    } 
    }
```

Counter.scala

```
 import akka.actor.Actor
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem
    import akka.actor.Props
    import akka.actor._
    class Counter extends Actor {
    val counts = HashMap[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
    def receive={
    case Page(title, text)=>
    for (word<-Words(text))
    counts(word) += 1
    sender ! Processed
    }
    }
```

Errors

[error] /home/ahsen/SbtPrctc/ProducerConsumer/src/main/scala/Counter.scala:6: not found: value HashMap

[error] val counts = HashMapString,Int.withDefaultValue(0)

[error]              ^

[error] /home/ahsen/SbtPrctc/ProducerConsumer/src/main/scala/Counter.scala:8: not found: value Page

[error] case Page(title, text)=>

[error]      ^

[error] /home/ahsen/SbtPrctc/ProducerConsumer/src/main/scala/Counter.scala:9: not found: value Words

[error] for (word<-Words(text))

[error]            ^

[error] /home/ahsen/SbtPrctc/ProducerConsumer/src/main/scala/Parser.scala:7: not found: value Pages

[error] val pages=Pages(100000, "enwiki.xml")

[error]           ^

i am sure i am doing some stupid mistake bt please help me out

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Java `HashMap` you need to `import java.util.HashMap`. However, I believe in your case you want to use the Scala `scala.collections.mutable.Map` (which you also need to import, and change `HashMap` to `Map`).

Also, please properly indent your code in your questions, and also mark the stack traces as code. It makes it much easier for respondents to read your questions.